# Running a java file without its corrosponding class file

Tags: java, jvm

I am facing a peculiar problem.

I have a `java` file that has a main method, inside of which I am doing a `System.out.Println("A");`

This file is compiled using `javac` and I get a `.class` file , which I run and get my result.

Now,
I change the code and add another `S.O.Println ("B")`. I compile and run but I get the previous output.

I have removed my class file, deleted it and still when I run it without even compiling it, I get my first output.

Is the JVM caching my first compiled .class file?

Can somebody tell me how can I get past this?

Comment: It will give an error, Could not find or load main class.

Comment: How are you running the program? Can you post the exact command you used to run it.

Comment: @Codebender , I am running from cmd prompt using
the command:  java server
compiling it with: javac server.java

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling to the directory that you think you're compiling to?

Comment: @mcfinnigan, yeah I am deleting the class file from that path then doing a javac server.java command , I see the class file getting created with the current time and when I run I am getting my previous output.

Comment: @user2210121, are you updating the same java file which you are compiling? Because java doesn't cache files or something.

Comment: @user2210121 delete the class file you think you execute and try running `java server` again. if that works you compile to a different directory

Comment: If it is still running the old code, there is a copy somewhere on your filesystem it is using.  I suggest you use an IDE or built tool.  As you get more complex projects, trying to do this manually will drive you mad.

Comment: Run you class as `java -verbose:class server | egrep -v "Loaded java.|Loaded sun.|rt.jar"` to see from where the `server.class` is loaded. The output would be something like `[Loaded server from file:/tmp/so/]`

Comment: @SubOptimal Thanks for the command it clearly showed that the server class was loaded from some other path.

Comment: so what I did was I had to add a jar file in the classpath variable prior to compiling my server.java file .. Now when I run my java file , clearly the latest server.java file is not running ....now If I explicitly mention my classpath again when running the java cmd like : java -cp . server.java then my latest file is getting EXECUTED. So I ran the command 
java -verbose:class server | egrep -v "Loaded java.|Loaded sun.|rt.jar"